# How to open Autodesk SDF file with Python

Tags: python, software-recommendations, autodesk, sdf

I'm trying to open a large SDF file (~8gb) in Python. I have been provided a layer in this SDF format (Autodesk SDF3), but I have so far been unsuccessful with opening this filetype with packages such as GeoPandas - and information regarding opening this filetype online with Python is limited.

Is there an appropriate package that would allow me to read this data?

Comment: For software recommendations there is the [softwarerecs.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: SDF is a proprietary Autodesk format. Open it in Map 3D and export to SHP.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up utilising a trial of FME Workbench to convert it to a JSON file which I could then read through python.